# Why does this reaction take place in terms of electronic structure?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, water, electronic-configuration, electronegativity

I need to know, in terms of electronic charge - the electrophiles and nucleophiles involved - how the electronegativity of the potassium and hydrogen atoms alongside the hydroxide and H<sup>+</sup> ions result in this reaction taking place. You could also think of this as asking why this reaction is exothermic from an organic chemistry perspective - why are the products more stable in terms of their electronic arrangement. It might be helpful to have the mechanism explained perhaps.

$$\ce{2K + 2H2O -> 2KOH + H2}$$

Of course, I have learnt before that potassium is higher up the reactivity series than hydrogen, but what does this mean on a deeper level - what factors mean that potassium is more reactive than hydrogen in terms of electron arrangement.

Comment: You can visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation "LaTex ‎at ‎chemistry.SE"), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/443/should-‎we-correct-math-formatting) and [this ‎one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111/formatting-sandbox-please-test-‎stuff-here)  on how to make your future posts better.‎

Comment: [[I edited the question to balance the reaction.  Only one mole of H2 is produced per 2 moles of K.]]